# Asking Error Macro Excell Compile Error: Expected: Identifier without type suffix

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with macro in it.
This error appears [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbES0.png) when it is opened in my working computer. But the error does not appear and and the file works normal in my friend's computer.

Once I open it in my home using my computer, it works normal (no error appears).

Already surfing and try many things (include repair the excel) but still does not work.
Anyone have faced the similar problem, please help to share how to solve?

thank you very much.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code please (also show which line the error occurs on).  Almost impossible to figure out why the error occurs without seeing what causes it.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)